# Как добавит элементы в FlexLayout не блокируя основной поток?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Здраствуйте.Имеется FlexLayout

```
         <ScrollView  Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
         
            <FlexLayout x:Name="flexLayout"
                    Wrap="Wrap"
                    JustifyContent="SpaceAround" >

            </FlexLayout>

         </ScrollView>
```

В него добавляются новые элементы,как только будет достигнута конец ScrollView.

```
private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollView scrollView = sender as ScrollView;
        int scrollingSpace = (int)(scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height);
        var scrollY =(int) e.ScrollY;
        
        if (scrollingSpace <= scrollY)
        {
          AddContent();
        }
     }
```

Метод AddContent() асинхронный.Но почему-то всё равно блокируется основной поток,во время загрузки длительностью в две секунды пользователь не может работать с ScrollView.
Как не заблокировать основной поток,во время загрузки элементов?
Спасибо за уделённое время.

```
async void AddContent() 
    {
        try
        {
            

            var ResultPhotoPexalNextPage = await pexelsClient.CuratedPhotosAsync(NamberPage,SizePage);
            NamberPage++;
            
            
            
            for (int i = 0; i < SizePage; i++)
            {

                ImageClass imageButton1 = new ImageClass
                    (
                      new ImageButton { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].source.medium)), StyleId = ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].photographerUrl },
                      url: ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].source.portrait,
                      Height_Image: ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].height,
                      Width_Image: ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].width,
                      photographer_url: ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].photographerUrl,
                      photographer_name: ResultPhotoPexalNextPage.photos[i].photographer
                    );


                };

                flexLayout.Children.Add(imageButton1.Image_button);

            }
           
            
            //DeleteLater
            Label1.Text = (GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1048576).ToString() + " MB";
            //
            

        }
        catch (Exception q)
        {
            

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: А XAML по вашей логике придуман просто так, для галочки? Чтоб вы сделали там один элемент и использовали далее его в коде? Не кажется, что вы делаете что-то не то?

Comment: Метод то асинхронный, и он сам по себе не блокирует, но код, которыц выполняется в нём, выполняется в UI потоке, то есть работа по прикручиванию картинок к контролам вам и подвешивает интерыфейс. Вынести в другой поток ее нельзя, потому что тогда невозможно будет работать с контролами. Поэтому я вам советую учить XAML и привящки данных (биндинги). Интрефейс умеет сам грузить картинки асинхронно, вы просто не используете эту возможность.

Comment: А как бы вы написали эту функциональность через биндинги?

Comment: Или напишите пожалуйста не большой пример на базе этого что бы знать где копать?

Comment: `как бы вы написали эту функциональность через биндинги` - Какую? Показывание картинок тогда, когда скрол дошел до конца? Подобное зовется "Виртуализацией", смысла вот так отлавливать событие скрола и добавлять поочередно элементы нету. Как и нету смысла делать нечто подобное `flexLayout.Children.Add(imageButton1.Image_button);`. Сделайте `ItemsControl` (или кто там у вас в Xamarin), задайте ему нужный вид, привяжите его к `ObservableCollection` с картинками, все, дальше работайте только с этой коллекцией, добавляя туда все что надо, не трогая как-либо XAML.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  можете стать моим ментором? Мне очень тяжело  приходиться  учить программирование.

Comment: @mdlcode Чтож вы себя так не цените. Программист обязан самостоятельно находить и познавать нужную информацию, а вы сразу "мне трудно", не уйдете вы так далеко... Я вам подсказал как нужно, подсказал какие технологии использовать, ищите, познавайте, задавайте отдельные вопросы тут, на SO, вам помогут. Попробуйте сначала просто привязать коллекцию ссылок на картинки и вывести это все на экран, а дальше уже развивайте это все, добавляя нужный функционал. Но помните, в C# не должно быть обращений к UI элементам, это плохо!